# Eclipselink create-or-extend-tables is not working

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to use the create-or-extend-tables of Eclipselink to create newly added columns. But the columns are not created in Database (MySQL). We are using EclipseLink 2.5.2 and Glassfish 4.1 (build 13).

Please any expert here help me on this.

```
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createSunriseDB.sql"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropSunriseDB.sql"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: Turn logging to finest and it might log what it is doing and show why it might not be modifying the tables as you expect. Glassfish is a container that is known to override and inject its own table creation logic into the container managed persistence unit though, so it is likely these settings aren't getting used or picked up. You would need to test these settings outside the container and then within it, and then check the glass fish docs.

Comment: How can I test outside the container?